# How to run Splunk stats command to get answers

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Anyone please tell me how to execute commands - stats to produce a report on the numbers of times the GAMES equals to FOOTBALL?

Answer (score 0):

index=... sourcetype=... GAMES=FOOTBALL | stats count